# In veracrypt, what happens if you select "none" in file system options when formatting a volume?

Tags: encryption

I searched google [reddit r/veracrypt](https://www.reddit.com/r/VeraCrypt/) and [the veracrypt guide](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Documentation.html) and couldn't find an answer, but i wanted to ask the following:

When you have the option to choose your file system, one of the options is "none" and i'm wondering what happens if you select that option and how your information is processed?

Comment: I think that should be, I deal the formating later.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, it skips that step, and the OS does not use the new storage volume for a filesystem.

You do not have to use the Verycrypt formatting option, you can use the OS formatting tools after the volume is created, or a third party tool if you are using an alternative filesystem such as EXT4.

Also, just because the OS cannot use an unformatted volume, it does not mean special tools cannot use it, but that is a risk, since the OS will commonly ask you to format an unformatted file system when it is mounted or accessed using the supplied file manager.